# Как создать тему для бота с помощью Pytelgramapi

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

День добрый. Необходимо реализовать бота, который будет принимать сообщение от пользователя и отправлять конечному пользователю. После чего может получить ответ. Т.е. практически как личная беседа, с 3-им лицом в виде бота. Была идея реализовать через второго бота, но задумался как будут отображаться сообщения при большом потоке сообщений. В связи с этим возникла идея для второй стороны будет канал в телеграмме разделённый на темы (уникальный пользователь). Тогда можно будет посмотреть всю переписку и дать более корректный ответ. Но не нашел возможно ли создать тему и перекидывать туда определённые сообщения через pytelegramapi. Нашел ответ только через asyncio, но когда весь код написал на Pytelegramapi, мне кажется будет трудновато всё переписать.

Со своей стороны я попробовал найти что-то в официальной документации, но не смог найти ответа...

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В телеграмме есть возможность канал разделить на темы. Вопрос в том можно ли реализовать данный функционал используя бота( что бы бот создавал новую тему на каждого нового пользователя, что бы можно было вести переписку с пользователем.